# Perl Mechanize - How to disable Kerberose?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I have a situation where i need to check for certain conditions of an Internal web application.

> 1. First i need to check if the application is loading or not. -- For this i have used Perl Mechanize module and using get method to load
>      the URl. The problem which i am facing was it was showing 401
>      unauthorized and if i send the username and password as parameters to
>      function "credentials" it works fine.

I Just want to check if the webpage is loading or not without entering the credentials? Printing a message if it loads looks fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a direct request with LWP and check the return code. If it is 401 you know that the server was responding. If this also means that your application is working depends on who is responsible for checking the authorization.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $resp = LWP::UserAgent->new->get('http://example.com');
if ($resp->code == 401) ...
```

Comment: so as per my understanding, you are asking me to do a regex match for "401"?

Comment: The OP is using WWW::Mechanize, and the exact same check can be done using WWW::Mechanize (being a subclass of LWP::UserAgent).